# Add libraries for static compilation CentOS 8

Tags: centos8

How do I install static versions of glibc on CentOS 8?

I am trying to compile a version of rsync using static linked libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I install static versions of glibc on CentOS 8

```
# dnf search glibc
# dnf provides */libc.a
         // both commands will (also) reply: glibc-static
# dnf install glibc-static
```

Note : glibc-static is in this repo: `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-PowerTools.repo`

```
# dnf config-manager --enable PowerTools
```

Package list, "PowerTools" http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/PowerTools/x86_64/os/Packages/

Example mirror, "PowerTools" http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/PowerTools/x86_64/os/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I get

No match for argument: glibc-static

Do I need to add a repo?

Comment: Please see my edited answer. ... Maybe your CentOS-PowerTools.repo is disabled ?

Comment: OK. I'll give that a go in a moment. Thanks again.

Comment: That's was it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I was on CentOS 8. The above answers worked, but I had to change

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

to:

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

Answer (score 0):

in centos8 docker containers:
while I'm trying enable PowerTools to use the command, it does not work:

```
 # dnf config-manager --enable PowerTools 
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C.UTF-8
No such command: config-manager. Please use /usr/bin/dnf --help
It could be a DNF plugin command, try: "dnf install 'dnf-command(config-manager)'"
```

Enable it with the following commands, then it worked:

```
yum install dnf-plugins-core
yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install dnf-plugins-core
yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
yum install glibc-static
yum install libstdc++-static
```

These worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me, had to read all suggestions before build proper one.

```
yum install -y dnf-plugins-core
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
yum install -y glibc-static
```